# Confusion in this and document Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, window, this, document

Actually i am learning javascript event these days but in between that i do some coding and the question arise in my mind that

Q1) when i create function and in that i write variable like (this.a = 4) than console it works fine and then i write document.a it also work fine so when we create object like this.name or etc so why we don't create like document.name or etc. thats confusing me ?

Q2) similarly i write a code

```js
if(document.addEventListener){
    document.getElementById('pink').addEventListener('click', function(){
        alert("Clicked on pink"); 
    },false);
} else{
    document.getElementById('pink').attachEvent('onclick', function(){
      alert("older Clicked on pink"); 
  });
}
```

or

```js
if(window.addEventListener){
    document.getElementById('pink').addEventListener('click', function(){
        alert("Clicked on pink"); 
    },false);
} else{
    document.getElementById('pink').attachEvent('onclick', function(){
      alert("older Clicked on pink"); 
  });
}
```

while both are working thats also make me confuse that window and document are two different things but still addEventListener is working in both ?

Answer (score 0):

> why we don't create like document.name or etc. thats confusing me ?

Code becomes harder to maintain if data is stored:

- as globals
- as properties on objects that have no particular association with that bit of data (especially of those objects are accessed via globals provided by the browser)

> window and document are two different things

Yes

> but still addEventListener is working in both

Events bubble.

You click on an element, and a click event is fired on that element.

Then a click event is fired on that element's parent node. Then that element's parent node and so on. Eventually it gets to the top of the DOM and hits the `document` object and then the `window` object.

```js
function listen(event) {
    console.log("Event caught by handler attached to " + this + " from click on " + event.target);  
}

addEventListener("click", listen);
document.addEventListener("click", listen);
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", listen);
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", listen);
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```